# Camera Calibration circular pattern

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm using a circular pattern calibration image (as below) to calibrate a pair of stereo cameras.

If I where using Matlab or/and OPEN CV , there are functions that automatically make the correspondence between image points and world points, in what concerns to checkerboard edges in the image (e.g. detectCheckerboardPoints in Matlab), so I don't have problems with image orientation.

I leave an image as example:
[image]

How can I make an automatic correspondence between random points detected, and an ordered grid of points in the real world (as a result of a self defined referencial)?

Comment: Thanks for the editing!

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: Thanks FooBar, I've already edited the question!

Comment: Obvious question first: Why? You can accurately find and match features using a checkerboard, so why go though this pain?

Comment: Because I want to make sure that I get the same result as a commercial software... that actually uses circles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by computing the convex hull of all detected circle centers and approximate the resulting polygon (so that it has 4 edges):

```
vector<Point> convex_hull;
vector<Point> poly_hull;
vector<Point> circle_centers;

// fill circle centers
...

// compute and approximate convex hull
convexHull( Mat( circle_centers ), convex_hull );
approxPolyDP( Mat( convex_hull ), poly_hull, 3, true );
```

The next step is to find the 4 circle centers that are the closest (in Euclidean distance) to the four poly_hull points: they are the four corners. Re-order them in a top-left first, clockwise manner and then you can make a first estimate of the affine transform:

```
vector<Point2f> dst_points;
vector<Point2f> src_points;
Rect canvas;

// fill in original canvas dimensions
...

// add source points
src_points.push_back( Point2f( canvas.tl() ) );
src_points.push_back( Point2f( canvas.width, 0 ) );
src_points.push_back( Point2f( canvas.br() ) );
src_points.push_back( Point2f( 0, canvas.height ) );

// add destination points
for ( int i = 0; i < poly_hull.size(); i++ )
    dst_points.push_back( poly_hull[i] );

// estimate transformation 
Mat transformation = estimateRigidTransform( src_points, dst_points, false );

if ( transformation.data != 0  )
{
    cout << "+++ AFFINE TRANSFORMATION ESTIMATE +++++++++++++++++++++++++++"<< endl;
    cout << "  + homography matrix: " << endl;
    cout << cv::format( "  +   [ %.3f %.3f %.3f ]", transformation.at<double>( 0, 0 ), transformation.at<double>( 0, 1 ), transformation.at<double>( 0, 2 ) ) << endl ;
    cout << cv::format( "  +   [ %.3f %.3f %.3f ]", transformation.at<double>( 1, 0 ), transformation.at<double>( 1, 1 ), transformation.at<double>( 1, 2 ) ) << endl ;
    cout << "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"<< endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "HOMOGRAPHY NO DATA" << endl;
}
```

After that you can possibly refine the affine estimate by finding more corresponding point pairs by using the 1st affine transformation to project ground-truth circle centers to the image space and look for the closest points. You can also look at cv::findHomography in that case if you suspect more than affine.

Comment: Thank you, but the function is already compatible with matlab mexopencv toolbox: http://kyamagu.github.io/mexopencv/